# Folder structure in react: Could not find a required file. Name: index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, directory-structure

So I moved the contents of my `src` folder into a folder i created called `app` folder. I am building my project a hospital management system with electronic patient records. I see a lot of future in this project so I want to Start well. The error I am getting is `Could not find a required file. Name: index.js` [screen shot of what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At7dR.png)

Comment: Did you also move the index.js file to app? If not create a file `index.js` in src folder and add a boilerplate to start render the react app.

Comment: React will search for your index.js in src folder, so you must recreate the src folder and then paste index.js in it from your actual app folder, so it will all start working again

Comment: Ok so I moved `index.js` into the `src` folder and I relinked `reportWebVitals.js` and `index.css` in the index.js file. It works now. Massive gratitude

Comment: @EfraimJerszurki thanks

Answer (score 1):

when working with react it suffices to create a file named index.js in the
src folder. this can be done by
-right clicking on the src folder
-choose new file
-name the file index.js
-press the enter key to create

then you can try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).